# Exclude php from url in get request

Tags: .htaccess

Is it possible to exclude the .php from URL?

Currently i got this in my .htaccess to remove php from urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But whenever i try to do

```
dashboard?test=lol
```

It doesn't work, but if i do

```
dashboard.php?test=lol
```

then it does work.

I've seen other sites being able to do it without the .php in url... so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the webserver?
You also need to enable AllowOverride in Apache configuration. Something similar to this:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing of URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your site root .htaccess to enable content negotiation:

```sh
Options +MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.